# Set complicated assumptions on symbolic function

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

I am trying to find the roots of a nonlinear function that depends on several symbolic variables and a symbolic function. To guarantee the existence of a solution I need to set some assumptions on the symbolic function `b(x)`. 
By using the Matlab function `assume` I can set simple assumptions like

```
syms b(x) d
assume(b(0)==0 & b(x)>=0);
```

Now I am looking for a way to include this assumption: (symbolic function `b(x)`, symbolic variable `d`)
There is a value `y` such that `b(x) < d*x` for `x < y` and `b(x) > d*x` for `x > y`.

To make it easier we can fix for example `d=0.1` and `b(10)=1` such that `y=10`. However I would prefer leaving `d` and `y` symbolic.

I tried to write a function that checks the assumption but unsurprisingly Matlab does not seem to accept a symbolic function as an input variable.

Do you know a solution to this problem or have an idea?

Update 2017-01-03:
While having fixed `d=0.1`,`b(10)=1` and `y=10` I am trying to check the above assumption by using

```
syms b(x) 
d=0.1;
assume(x, 'real');
assume(x>=0);
assume(b(0)==0 & b(x)>=0 & b(10)==1);
checkAssumption(x)= mySign(x)*(d*x-b(x)); 
assume(checkAssumption(x)>=0);
```

where

```
function sign=mySign(x)
if x<10
    sign=-1;
else if x==10
        sign=0;
    else if x>10
            sign=-1;
        end
    end
end
```

Then I get the error "Conversion to logical from sym is not possible." in mySign. Using `double(x)` as the input variable of mySign leads to the error "DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array".

Do you know a way to get `mySign` and `checkAssumptions` evaluated or have an other idea how to assume the above assumption?

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible. A symbolic isn't sufficiently well defined to prove something analytically. Also, note that symbolic variables (and symbolic functions too probably) are complex-valued by default.

Comment: Is `b(x)` arbitrary or does it have a specific definition?

Comment: The function `b(x)` is arbitrary but has to satisfy the assumptions above. Please excuse my imprecise formulation: by "complex" I didn't mean complex numbers but "not simple".